# Rails ActiveRecord Perform Group, Sum and Count in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have two tables,

```
Order (ID, Value)
```

and

```
OrderType (ID, Name [Quote, Sale, Purchase, etc])
```

I want to get the total number of orders in each type (count) and the total value of those orders per type (sum)

I can get these individually using

```ruby
Order.group(:order_type).count(:id)
```

and

```
Order.group(:order_type).sum(:value)
```

I would like to perform these in one query, the equivalent to the following SQL

```sql
SELECT
  order_types.id, Count(*) as total_count, Sum(orders.value) As total_value
FROM
  order
JOIN
  order_types ON orders.order_type_id = order_types.ID
GROUP BY
  order_types.id
```

The query should also return the full `OrderType` object so I can display the name in my view

Answer (score 14):

Since ActiveRecord does not support multiple aggregation functions in the same query, you need to do a bit of raw SQL to achieve this.

```
grouped_sales = OrderType
  .select('order_types.id, order_types.name, 
     sum(orders.value) as sale, count(*) as purchase')
  .join('JOIN orders ON orders.order_type_id = order_types.id')
  .group('order_types.id')
```

The point to note here is that you need to use an existing column in OrderType as the alias for your aggregated columns. Here you will get the OrderType object as well.

To access the result:

```
id -> grouped_sales.first.id
name -> grouped_sales.first.name
total orders -> grouped_sales.first.sale
order value -> grouped_sales.first.purchase
```

Answer (score 10):

There is even better solution, just:

`.pluck('sum(orders.value), count(*)').first`

Comment: I know this does not solve all the questions the user had, but to me, this solves every problem I had in the last 2 months. It is the *best* way to query count and sum with one query. As a side note, you can combine this with `#group` and get categorised results

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays pluck+arel will do the job.

```
model = Model.arel_table
Model.group(:order_type).pluck(model[:id].count, model[:value].sum)
```

Also appending with .order(:order_type) may be needed if there applied default ordering by ID.

Comment: Thanks, I use this shortening and optimize query